# Printing Control Characters in C

Tags: c

Is there a standard way in C to print control character using caret notation, so that rather than '\037' for printing ascii char 31, it would print '^C' or '^D'?

```
(gdb) p/c 33
$5 = 33 '!'
(gdb) p/c 32
$6 = 32 ' '
(gdb) p/c 31
$7 = 31 '\037'
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess your question is how to put characters in that notation in GDB? If your question is about standalone C, why don't use a simple lookup table?

```
static const char const *CTRL_CODES[32] = {
    "^@",
    "^A",
    ... // C.f. http://www.bbdsoft.com/ascii.html
};
```

Comment: That would work; do you know if this is already included somewhere in a file that can be included?  Don't want to code something that's already been done.

Comment: I do not think that this is already defines in some standard import. As @modifiable lvalue says in his answer, C does not assume that you are using ASCII/Latin1/whatever.

Answer (score 0):

No. The standard doesn't require that ASCII be used as the execution character set.

Comment: Are you sure that the notation is different in EBCDIC? (Otherwise you are right, of cause, C does not assume the data to be ASCII.)

Comment: The standard doesn't require EBCDIC, either.

Comment: That's right, too. But to tell the truth: Nobody gives a … about EBCDIC, and neither does anyone care about any other char code, either.

Comment: The question asks about *a standard way in C*, to print something that the C standard doesn't have. Please show me where in the C standard I can find ^C or ^D.

Comment: To clarify: There are 99 characters that C does require during execution, but if you look for ASCII (or EBCDIC) 0 through to 31, most of them *aren't* required during execution.

Comment: As you quite surely know, there is no standard import that defines that `C` follows `D` in some or another semantic. But to tell to the truth, SO is not about to find every and each ineligibility, but to help OP.

Comment: You both make good points, but if I had to pick a side it would be to accept that the OP wants to print ASCII control characters.  I think it's more useful to point them in *some* direction with a warning than it is to point them in *no* direction with an uncompromising interpretation of their question.  The combination of your two answers seems to provide a single satisfactory answer.